# Is there a function which can match wildcard and replace with string - javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am Developing a project using javascript, php. I need to match wildcard string using javascript like

```
//users need to enter some url in textbox like strings_1 or strings_2
var strings_1='http://google.com/search?q=Hello World&o=test';
var strings_2='http://google.com/?q=Hello world&o=test';

var search_reg='*//google.com/search?q=*&o=*';
// match each url string_1 and 2 with search_reg, if any string match it should replace * by $1, $2, $3
var final_url_should_be='$1//otherengine/test?q=$2&o=$3';
```

so final url should be http://otherengine/test?q=Hello World&o=test

Answer (score 0):

Using regex

```js
//users need to enter some url in textbox like strings_1 or strings_2
var strings_1 = 'http://google.com/search?q=Hello World&o=test';
var strings_2 = 'http://google.com/?q=Hello world&o=test';

var search_reg = '*//google.com/search?q=*&o=*';
// match each url string_1 and 2 with search_reg, if any string match it should replace * by $1, $2, $3
var final_url_should_be = '$1//otherengine/test?q=$2&o=$3';

console.log(replaceUrl(strings_1));

console.log(replaceUrl(strings_2));

function replaceUrl(inputUrl) {
return inputUrl.replace(/\bsearch/,'').replace(/\bgoogle.com\//, 'otherengine/test');
}
```

But if you know the exact words in url(like google.com) which should be replaced, then plain `replace()` will work, without any regex.

```js
//users need to enter some url in textbox like strings_1 or strings_2
var strings_1 = 'http://google.com/search?q=Hello World&o=test';
var strings_2 = 'http://google.com/?q=Hello world&o=test';

var search_reg = '*//google.com/search?q=*&o=*';
// match each url string_1 and 2 with search_reg, if any string match it should replace * by $1, $2, $3
var final_url_should_be = '$1//otherengine/test?q=$2&o=$3';

console.log(replaceUrl(strings_1));

console.log(replaceUrl(strings_2));

function replaceUrl(inputUrl) {

  return inputUrl.replace('search', '').replace('google.com/', 'otherengine/test');
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, but i forget to tell you that regex should also be enter by users.

Chrome Extenstion https://app.requestly.in/rules/ has facility where users can set rule to redirect automatically urls to another
url wildcard match --   *://www.google.*/search?q=*&*
Destination Url -   $1://duckduckgo.com/?q=$3&$4

Answer (score 0):

If you're just swapping the domains, you can do it this way as well:

`/(?<domain>https?:\/\/.*[.][a-zA-Z0-9]{3}\/)(?<path>.*\?.*[=].*)/`

You can access the named capture group in regex, and use interpolation to get your results

```js
var strings_1='http://google.com/search?q=Hello World&o=test';
var strings_2='http://google.com/?q=Hello world&o=test';

var newDomain="https://newdomain.com/";


const replace1 = strings_1.replace( /(?<domain>https?:\/\/.*[.][a-zA-Z0-9]{3}\/)(?<path>.*\?.*[=].*)/, `${newDomain}$<path>`);


console.log(replace1);
```